# How to prevent 'finished' GWT-modules from recompiling when deploying to GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, module, gae-module

Is there something I can do to not have *all* my modules recompiled every time I hit 'Deploy to GAE'? (Like when I don't touch GWT or client-side at all.)

It would be nice to see 'module not modified, skipping...' sometimes, instead of 'compiling 12 permutations, go get me a coffee...'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having an ant script that generates the war after each compile... that way you can just upload the war with no questions asked. The time spent creating the war is negligible compared to the time it takes to do a GWT compile anyway.

Comment: i will try 'appcgf update' for the starters, but thank you, your advice has lead me to that executable :)